# Are the following statements true for matrix elementary row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if the following statements about ERO's (elementary row operations) are mathematically correct. Any help and insight is appreciated. Any additional facts to the table is also welcomed.

**ERO's performed on a matrix $A$ will preserve**

1) The row space of the matrix A

2) The null space of the matrix A

3) Any linear dependence or independence of the columns of $A$

**ERO's performed on a matrix $A$ will *NOT* preserve**

1) The column space of the matrix $A$

2) Any linear dependence or independence of the rows of $A$

> note that the preservation of linear dependence / independence refers to preserving not just if the set of vectors is linearly dependent / independent - but also the exact relationships between the vectors themselves (e.g. vector #1 is exactly 2x that of vector #3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have now is correct (see the edit I made).

I would also add: ERO's preserve the *dimension* of the columns space (and nullspace of $A^T$), even if they don't preserve the spaces precisely.  Also, "the linear dependencies of the columns of $A$" is **precisely** the information conveyed by the nullspace of $A$.  That is: for any $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $x_1 \mathbf a_1 + \cdots + x_n \mathbf a_n = 0$, we have
$$
A \pmatrix{x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_n} = \pmatrix{0 \\ \vdots \\ 0}
$$
Similarly, the nullspace of $A^T$ conveys the linear dependencies of the rows of $A$.

Comment: Ive seen that you changed the original `Any linear independence of the columns of A`. But I just did it on paper. Consider the following http://i.imgur.com/rHTsRXI.jpg

Comment: It is not at all clear to me which row operations you used to go from the first matrix to the second matrix (it should be impossible to do so).  In any case, you had the exact same statement in both categories, and you know that can't be right.

Comment: The first statement was `linear dependence` the second statement was `linear independence`. The 2 ERO's I used was simultaneously adding the rows to each other

Comment: That is **not** an elementary row operation.  You can replace **one** of the rows with the sum of two rows, but you can't do that to both rows simultaneously. At least, that is not what is *usually* meant by "elementary row-operation".

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the **source of my confusion**. One last sanity check. When you say preserve independence/dependence of columns/rows. Do you mean just the state of the vectors? `oh, yeah the set of rows/columns are linearly independent/dependent`. Or do you mean that it also preserves the exact relation between them? `oh, yeah the row/column #1 is 2x that of row/column #3`.

Comment: I mean the second thing.  That second thing is exactly the information that is conveyed by the nullspaces of $A$ and of $A^T$, as I try to clarify in my answer.

Comment: A humble student thanks you for your help

Comment: Would ECO's (elementary column operations) just be the same table but reversed? (e.g. the top `will preserve` will simply become the bottom `will not preserve`)? Or would it be something different altogether?

Comment: @Alan yes. It's the same as applying EROs to $A^T$.